# when clicked on the Reject Button , i need to open the dialog box , capture the message and do an update to the database reason for rejection

Tags: jquery

I have a requirement where when clicked on the Reject Button , i need to open the dialog box , capture the message and do an update to the database reason for rejection

```
 <div id="reasonforrejectdiv">
 <textarea id="txtArea" rows="10" cols="10" style="margin: 0px; width: 276px; height: 225px;"></textarea>
</div>


<input type="button" id="rejectcategory" class="btn blue" value="Reject This Category">
```

I have done this way

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#reasonforrejectdiv").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Close Dialog": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function (ev, ui) {
            return true;
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '#rejectcategory', function (event) {
    $("#reasonforrejectdiv").dialog("open");
    // capture the Text Entered here and do an ajax call
    //    var val = $("#txtArea").val();
    // alert(val);
    // do an ajax call here 
});
```

But i am facing some problems (The text i am capturing is empty ) and where do an ajax call ??

http://jsfiddle.net/SWyuU/194/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#reasonforrejectdiv").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Close Dialog": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function (ev, ui) {
           console.log($("#txtArea").val());
          ///after this ajax call will work
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```